# re.rompile returns true with false, not allow symbols

Tags: python

Im trying to use regex do check a variable for accepted letters and numbers. This is my def:

```
def special_match(strg, search=re.compile(r'[a-z0-9]').search):
 if bool(search(strg)) is True:
    print ('Yes: ' + strg)
 elif:
    print ('nej: ')

while 1:
    variabel = raw_input('Enter something: ')
    special_match(variabel)

sys.exit()
```

And it seems that is accepts not allow symbols in combination with allow symbols:

```
Enter something: qwerty
Yes: qwerty
Enter something: 1234
Yes: 1234
Enter something: !!!!      
nej!
Enter something: 1234qwer!!!!
Yes: 1234qwer!!!!
Enter something:
```

The last one should not be accepted.. What I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your regular expression search is doing is checking to see if at least *one* of the characters is present.

If you want to require that the entire string contains nothing but those characters, then you can use:

```
r'^[a-z0-9]*$'
```

That anchors the pattern at both the start and end of the string, and only matches if all of the characters in between are in the specified set of characters.

Note that this will also match the empty string.  If you wish to require at least one character, then you can change the `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 1):

the `search` method finds for regex you gave and if it finds then returns a `Match` object here `1234qwer!!!` has `[a-z0-9]` but `!!!!` doesnt. 
Try `a!!!`. that will also return True.
You could try doing

`re.search(r"[^a-z0-9]",word)`
and if this returns `True` that means your word has something other than digits and alphabets and that should be rejected.

NOTE: `^` means not.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that regex does is check that there is a number or a letter in your string. If you want to check that it *only* has numbers and letters, you need to anchor your pattern at the start and end, and add a repeat: `r'^[a-z0-9]+$'`

Note though that there is no need to use regex for this: the string `isalnum()` method will do the same thing.

There are a couple of other odd things in your code; you should definitely not be compiling a regex in the function signature and passing on the resulting search method; also you should not be converting the result to bool explicitly, and you should not compare bools with `is True`. A more Pythonic version, assuming you wanted to stick to the regex, would be:

```
def special_match(strg, search=None):
    if not search:
       search = re.compile(r'[a-z0-9]').search
    if search(strg):
       print ('Yes: ' + strg)
    else:
       print ('nej: ')
```

Also note `elif` is a syntax error on its own.